# Ford Focus 1.6 Diesel hissing noise

Tags: ford, noise, diesel, focus, tdci

My 2010 Ford Focus zetec 1.6 Diesel Tdci sounds like it's hissing when it's cold. Once it's up to temp dissapears.
I've only had the car a few weeks so is all new to me(cars in general).

The car drives fine apart from some kangaroo hopping in 2nd gear and pulling to the left(that will be for another post).

I have a video of the noise on youtube here: [Ford Focus Noise Youtube](https://youtu.be/gNxnudWxeHs)

Any advice appreciated, it may be perfectly normal for a diesel engine but the only diesel engines I'm used to have been on fork trucks.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a squeaking ancillary belt (fan belt) to me.  This belt drives things like the alternator.  May just need adjusting, but may need replacing.

Sometimes the noise changes when you add electrical load to the alternator by turning the lights on and the window demister etc.

Comment: Is it normal for it to go once warmed up?

Comment: Yes, as the rubber belt warms up, the rubber can become more sticky, so it grips better and the noise goes away.

Comment: Makes sense, so bit like valve or timing chain noise(I'm used to bike engines). I'll check that belt out thanks!